# Specify File-level FTP Permissions

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, permissions, ftp

I have a user that has access to an ftp folder:

```
/home/user1/public_html/
```

Is it possible to deny access to specific files within this folder, while still allowing `apache` to run them?

For example, `/home/user1/public_html/test.php`, I do not want the user to read/view this file, but I DO want `apache` to be able to run it normally.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is yes.

The how is by simply setting the correct owner and file-system permissions.
In some cases file-system ACL's (`setfacl`) provide the additional ganularity you might need.

Typically though you would restrict FTP users with chroot to their home-directories and move content your users are not allowed to see/edit/remove to a separate location outside their home directory and make that only reachable with the [**`Alias`**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) directive.